Can Dickson's conjecture with $b_i=1$ be proven for one $n,$ given that there are no obvious divisibility restrictions preventing this from happening?
I was reading this answer to it's question, and came across Dickson's Conjecture, because I was independently investigating the case where $b_i=1$ for $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}.$
Dickson's conjecture says essentially that for any $a_1,a_2 \dotsc a_k$ and $b_1, b_2 \dotsc b_k$, there are infinitely many $n$ where $a_i + b_i n$ are prime for all $1 \leq i \leq k$ unless there is an obvious divisibility restriction preventing this from happening.
As previously mentioned, I am currently interested in the case where $b_i=1$ for $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}.$ My question is:

For any $a_1,a_2 \dotsc a_k,$ can it be proven elementarily that there
is (at least) one $n$ such that $a_i + n$ are prime for all $1 \leq i
 \leq k$, given that (we have shown that) there is no obvious
divisibility restriction on the $a_i$ preventing this from happening?


The answer to the MO question here says "one prime value in suitable generality implies infinitely many prime values" in the setting of Bunyakovsky's conjecture, which is about prime values of a single polynomial. The end of the answer shifts attention to prime values of a finite set of polynomials with a similar conclusion: one prime value in suitable generality implies infinitely many prime values.  This argument is made using a change of variables $x \mapsto x+c$ or $x \mapsto qx$. Using the first change of variables doesn't affect leading coefficients, so with that kind of change, knowing a single prime value is attained whenever you expect infinitely many prime values to be attained actually implies infinitely many prime values are attained.  See Ribenboim, Book of Prime Number Records, Chapter 6, Section I, proof that $(D_0)$ implies $(D)$.

Let me just make clear what I said in the comment.
Suppose you prove what you want.
Then for every $k$,
you will have known that there exists $n$ such that
$n,n+2,n+6k,n+6k+2$ are all primes.
You will then have solved the twin prime conjecture.
In fact, by selecting $a_i$ carefully, you will have proven that for arithmetic progressions of primes of a fixed length $b$, infinitely many of them will have a common difference of exactly $b!$ which...
I'm no expert in analytic number theory but my gut tells me the latter goes way, way beyond the known proofs of long arithmetic progressions of primes and bounded gaps for pairs of primes.
